# In didSelectViewController function, scrollToTop not working on tapping tabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    tabBarController = self.router.tabController;

    for(UINavigationController* view in tabBarController.viewControllers) {
        UIViewController* topView = view.topViewController;
        if([topView isKindOfClass:[DiscussMainViewController class]]) {
            viewController = (DiscussMainViewController*)view;
            break;
        } else if([topView isKindOfClass:[JobsMainViewController class]]) {
            viewController = (JobsMainViewController*)view;
            break;
        } else if([topView isKindOfClass:[DailyListViewController class]]) {
            viewController = (DailyListViewController*)view;
            break;
        } else if([topView isKindOfClass:[ProfileTableViewController class]]) {
            viewController = (ProfileTableViewController*)view;
            break;
        }

    }

    if([viewController isEqual:tabBarController.selectedViewController]) {
        if([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollToTop)]) {
            [viewController performSelector:@selector(scrollToTop) withObject:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

whereas, scrollToTop function in all view controllers.. is like that

```
- (void)scrollToTop {
    [self.table setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: did you check it goes into condition :  [viewController performSelector:@selector(scrollToTop) withObject:nil];

Comment: [mainTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO]; try this